# When i try to update saved data into realm it is crashing, Image is becoming nil while updating

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, realm

When i'm saving it taking normally and saving.
When i try to update any thing, Image is becoming nil and displaying blank image and 
when i perform take camera action remaining data is becoming nil,Just opening camera remaining data will become nill.

Main problem is why Image is becoming nil when updating remaining all remains same. Only image will be null.

What can i do to solve this?

```
    //Navigation and ImagePicekrDelegate are for camera
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
    @IBOutlet weak var showImage: UIImageView!

    var itemImageVar :UIImage? {
        didSet{

        }

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        showImage.image = itemImageVar
    }

    //TODO: Saving image Here
    var imageData:Data?

    //Select Picture
    @IBAction func choosePhotAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary  //This is for opening photo library
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

   @IBAction func takePhotoActionw(_ sender: UIButton) {
        imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let imageViewer = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] {
            imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true,completion: nil)
            showImage.image = imageViewer as! UIImage
            saveImage(image: imageViewer as! UIImage)
        }
    }

    func saveImage(image : UIImage) {
        imageData = (image as! UIImage).jpegData(compressionQuality: 100)
        print(imageData)
    }

    @IBAction func saveBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let newArray = Items()//Item is realm Data Model
        newArray.itemName = itemName.text!


 if let data = imageData as Data?  {
                                newArray.itemImage = data
                            }


        newArray.dateWise = Date()

        //MARK: Realm data
        //Creating/saving data here
        if saveFlag == true {
            //This will go to Create data and save
            self.saveItems(item: newArray)
        } else {
            newArray.id = idVar!
            self.updateItems(item: newArray)
        }

        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
   }

    func saveItems(item: Items) {
        do {
           try realm.write { //Save/Create
               realm.add(item)
            }
        } catch {
           print("Error in saving \(error)")
        }
    }

   func updateItems(item: Items) {
       do {
           try realm.write {//Save/Create
              realm.add(item, update: .modified)
           }
       } catch {
           print("Error in saving \(error)")
       }
   }

   //Read the data after saving like displying again
   func displayItems() {
      itemArray = realm.objects(Items.self)
   }
```

Displaying ViewController : -

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemDispplayCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemDispplayCell

            if let cellItems = itemArray?[indexPath.row] {

                if let data = item.itemImage as Data? {
                                                 cell.circleImag.image = UIImage(data: data)
                                         }


            }else {
                cell.itemName.text = "No Items Added"
            }


            return cell
           }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 if let item = itemArray?[indexPath.row] {

            if let data = item.itemImage as Data?  {
                vc.imageVar = UIImage(data: data)
                                          }

}

    func displayItems() {

              itemArray  = realm.objects(Items.self)


            tableView.reloadData()

           }
```

Comment: what type of  `imageData` here `newArray.itemImage = imageData as NSData`

Comment: var imageData:Data?

Comment: where you give it a value

Comment: please share more code

Comment: please check question again , i update the code.

Comment: The issue is that `cellItems.itemImage` is nil. Generally speaking, you should always assume an optional could be nil and handle those cases accordingly. So you'll need to fix that in general but your first step is to determine if that property is nil and if it is, need to look at your code that writes the object out in the first place.

Comment: Also - your code formatting is a mess; I fixed the top section of code, but going forward, please format your code because as is, it's very difficult to read.

Comment: I think the imagePickerController should have `[String: Any]` instead of `[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]`. You may also want to look into `didFinishPickingImage` as it's a bit cleaner when working with just images.

Comment: In response to your comment in the answer, please see the above comments, clean up your code so it's readable, add a breakpoint and step through you code examining the variables. When one isn't what you expect that's where the issue is - we need more info to be of further help.

Comment: i debug that thing when i'm updating anything image becoming nil,While updating only it is becoming nil.

Comment: I don't know what that means, the question is unclear and the code is too hard to read. Voting to close until the question is clarified.

Answer (score 0):

Crash happens because you are force unwraping optional value. There are better ways to handle such cases. For example using `if let`:

```
if let data = cellItems.itemImage as? Data {
    cell.circleImag.image = UIImage(data: data)) 
}
```

And if you want to get `Data` from UIImage you shouldn't use `imageData as Data?` but rather:

```
let data = image.pngData()
```

Comment: as in my answer you have to set `imageData` inside `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`  , this answer will avoid the crash but won't solve it

Comment: Make sure that you setting imageData to item. Btw. your code is really badly formatted and it makes it hard to follow.

Comment: For clarity, while this answer contains very good information (it addresses how to handle optionals when they are nil) and getting pngData from an Image object - it doesn't have anything to do with the question which is why the var is nil in the first place as the OP doesn't feel it should be. The question states *(I) don't know why it is becoming nil*.

Comment: Only image is problem, While updating it is becoming nill. What to do?